# How to have different backgrounds for different screens ReactJS

Tags: html, css, reactjs, web-applications

I am trying to add backgrounds to screens in my ReactJS project through css, but when I add a background to the body of one screen (component), it appears on all the screens. All my components are in the same folder.

I have tried using the `!important` keyword but that is not making any difference.

Here is the css code i write for the screens I want a background on:

```
body {
    background: url("blue-bg.jpg");
}
```

Trying to have a background on a div instead of the body may not be the solution as the div doesn't cover the whole screen, which is not what I want.

Comment: Could you create a wrapper component that covers the whole screen?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use context API for theming or CSS theme like postcss support that functionality